# Perl CGI.pm module wildly out-of-date on RedHat/CentOS 5

Tags: redhat, perl, cgi, bugzilla

I am trying to install all my Perl modules from RPM (using rpmforge.net), instead of just acquiring them from CPAN.

My ultimate goal is to get Bugzilla 3.4.4 running.  It requires CGI.pm 3.21 or later; the perl package on RHEL5 (5.8.8) comes with CGI.pm 3.15, and it doesn't appear that any of the 3rd-party package repositories package it seperately (there is no longer a perl-CGI RPM for Red Hat: since RH9, it appears!)

Is there a recommended solution?

Comment: Yay! Tumbleweed badge! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./install-module.pl CGI` in your Bugzilla install folder will install a Bugzilla-local copy of the latest CGI.pm (under `<bugzilla-directory>/lib`.  This wont affect your yum managed packages at all.

Comment: I don't like to have to do this, but it's what I ended up doing.  Plus, you're new, so you're deserving of some points for a good answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you install all software with rpm, you should install Bugzilla with it too. There is no CGI.pm 3.2.1 - CGI.pm has one-dot version number. CGI.pm is a core module, so it is usually updated when Perl is updated or with cpan shell.

Comment: We are installing Bugzilla from source as it's a web application that we make customizations to, and we keep in our SVN tree; we're happy with that, but I want to keep libraries installed by RPM wherever possible.  The extra dots in the version number were a typo based on Bugzilla's x.y.z numbering, my mistake.  I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very careful not to replace the version of CGI.pm Red Hat ships with RHEL5, but you could install [cpan2rpm](http://perl.arix.com/cpan2rpm/), download [CGI.pm-3.21.tar.gz](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/CGI.pm-3.21.tar.gz), build your own RPM with:

```
$ cpan2rpm CGI.pm-3.21.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
> install CGI
```